# How to bend arrows properly between distant nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikz-arrows

[image]

The problem I have, I do not want these  two bend arrows to cross other nodes, how do I do that?

The code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

%nodes
\node [ellipse,draw=black, fill=green!20, minimum size = 2cm] (ctld) at (0,0) {slurmctld};
\node [rectangle,draw=black,rounded corners, fill=green!20, minimum size = 2cm, dashed] (dbd) at (3,0) {slurmdbd};
\node [rectangle,draw=black,rounded corners, fill=blue!20, minimum size = 2cm] (db) at (6,0) {database};
\node [rectangle,draw=black,rounded corners, fill=blue!20, minimum size = 2cm] (pmix) at (-3,0) {PMIx3};
\node [rectangle,draw=black,rounded corners, fill=blue!20, minimum size = 2cm] (mpi) at (-6,0) {OpenMPI};
\node [rectangle,draw=black,rounded corners, fill=red!20, minimum size = 2cm] (cuda) at (-6,-6) {CUDA};
\node [rectangle,draw=black,rounded corners, fill=red!20, minimum size = 2cm] (ib) at (-6,-10) {infiniband};
\node [ellipse,draw=black, fill=green!20, minimum size = 2cm] (sl1) at (-3,-6) {slurmd};
\node [ellipse,draw=black, fill=green!20, minimum size = 2cm] (sl2) at (0,-6) {slurmd};
\node [ellipse,draw=black, fill=green!20, minimum size = 2cm] (sl3) at (4,-6) {slurmd};
\node [rectangle,draw=black,rounded corners, fill=blue!20, minimum size = 2cm] (si1) at (-3,-10) {singularity};
\node [rectangle,draw=black,rounded corners, fill=blue!20, minimum size = 2cm] (si2) at (0,-10) {singularity};
\node [rectangle,draw=black,rounded corners, fill=blue!20, minimum size = 2cm] (si3) at (4,-10) {singularity};

% boxes
\node[draw, thick, dotted, rounded corners, inner xsep=1em, inner ysep=1em, fit=(sl1) (sl2) (sl3)] (slbox) {};
\node[draw, thick, dotted, rounded corners, inner xsep=1em, inner ysep=1em, fit=(si1) (si2) (si3)] (sibox) {};

%arrows
\path[every node] (mpi) edge[<->, thick] node [auto] {} (pmix);
\path[every node] (pmix) edge[<->, thick] node [auto] {} (ctld);
\path[every node] (ctld) edge[<->, thick] node [auto] {} (dbd);
\path[every node] (dbd) edge[<->, thick] node [auto] {} (db);
\path[every node] (mpi) edge[<->, thick, dashed, bend right=70] node [auto] {} (sibox);
\path[every node] (pmix) edge[<->, thick, dashed, bend right=70] node [auto] {} (sibox);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For repeating tasks like this it would make sense to create a dedicated `to path`.

You can think of a `to path` as being a wrapper for a path that takes two arguments. The first argument is the starting point and the second argument is the target point. Inside the wrapper you can refer to the points with `\tikztostart` and `\tikztotarget`.

Here is a typical example:

Please keep in mind that i have chosen the simplest form of bending by just rounding the corners of the path. However it should be easy to adjust the example to your needs.

If you still have questions please let us know.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[hmargin=2cm]{geometry}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes, fit}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        scale=0.82,
        dedicated to path/.style = {
            rounded corners=1em,
            to path = {
               (\tikztostart.north) -- ++(0,#1) -- ++(-4*#1,0) \tikztonodes coordinate(aux) --
                (aux |- \tikztotarget.south) -- ++(0,-#1) coordinate(aux) -- (aux-|\tikztotarget.south)  -- (\tikztotarget.south)
            }
        }
    ]

    %nodes
    \node [ellipse,draw=black, fill=green!20, minimum size = 2cm] (ctld) at (0,0) {slurmctld};
    \node [rectangle,draw=black,rounded corners, fill=green!20, minimum size = 2cm, dashed] (dbd) at (3,0) {slurmdbd};
    \node [rectangle,draw=black,rounded corners, fill=blue!20, minimum size = 2cm] (db) at (6,0) {database};
    \node [rectangle,draw=black,rounded corners, fill=blue!20, minimum size = 2cm] (pmix) at (-3,0) {PMIx3};
    \node [rectangle,draw=black,rounded corners, fill=blue!20, minimum size = 2cm] (mpi) at (-6,0) {OpenMPI};
    \node [rectangle,draw=black,rounded corners, fill=red!20, minimum size = 2cm] (cuda) at (-6,-6) {CUDA};
    \node [rectangle,draw=black,rounded corners, fill=red!20, minimum size = 2cm] (ib) at (-6,-10) {infiniband};
    \node [ellipse,draw=black, fill=green!20, minimum size = 2cm] (sl1) at (-3,-6) {slurmd};
    \node [ellipse,draw=black, fill=green!20, minimum size = 2cm] (sl2) at (0,-6) {slurmd};
    \node [ellipse,draw=black, fill=green!20, minimum size = 2cm] (sl3) at (4,-6) {slurmd};
    \node [rectangle,draw=black,rounded corners, fill=blue!20, minimum size = 2cm] (si1) at (-3,-10) {singularity};
    \node [rectangle,draw=black,rounded corners, fill=blue!20, minimum size = 2cm] (si2) at (0,-10) {singularity};
    \node [rectangle,draw=black,rounded corners, fill=blue!20, minimum size = 2cm] (si3) at (4,-10) {singularity};

    % boxes
    \node[draw, thick, dotted, rounded corners, inner xsep=1em, inner ysep=1em, fit=(sl1) (sl2) (sl3)] (slbox) {};
    \node[draw, thick, dotted, rounded corners, inner xsep=1em, inner ysep=1em, fit=(si1) (si2) (si3)] (sibox) {};


    \foreach[count=\i] \j/\k in {mpi/ib,pmix/si1,ctld/si2} {
        \draw[->, >=stealth] (\j) to[dedicated to path=\i] node[above]{Annotation \i} (\k);
    }


    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Similar idea of where to draw bent arrows as in @user1146332 answer, but whole code is quite shorter. It use `chains` TikZ library and predefined styles for nodes shapes. Arrows are draw directly:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                fit,
                shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.82,
           node distance = 8mm and 4mm,
             start chain = going right,
             base/.style = {draw, minimum size = 2cm, on chain},
                E/.style = {base, ellipse, fill=green!20, inner xsep=-1ex]},
                F/.style = {draw, thick, dotted, rounded corners, inner sep=2mm, fit=#1},
                R/.style = {base, rounded corners, fill=#1},
                R/.default = blue!20,
                        ]
%nodes
\node [R] (mpi)     {OpenMPI};
\node [R] (pmix)    {PMIx3};
\node [E] (ctld)    {slurmctld};
\node [R=green!30, dashed] (dbd)    {slurmdbd};
\node [R] (db)      {database};
%
\node [R=red!20, below=16mm of mpi] (cuda) {CUDA};
\node [E] (sl1)     {slurmd};
\node [E] (sl2)     {slurmd};
\node [R] (sl3)     {slurmd};
%
\node [R=red!20, below=of cuda] (ib)   {infiniband};
\node [R] (si1)     {singularity};
\node [R] (si2)     {singularity};
\node [R] (si3)     {singularity};
% fit boxes
\node[F=(sl1) (sl2) (sl3)] (slbox) {};
\node[F=(si1) (si2) (si3)] (sibox) {};
% connections
\foreach[count=\i] \j/\k in {mpi/ib,pmix/si1}
{
\draw[thick, densely dashed, rounded corners=3mm, -stealth] 
    (\j.north)  -- ++ (0,\i*4mm) 
                -|  ([xshift=-\i*5mm] mpi.west) 
                |-  ([yshift=-\i*5mm] ib.south)
                -|  (\k);
}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]